# Encode SMIME to pkijs to Openssl and Back

Tags: javascript, openssl, pki, smime, client-side-scripting

I'm having issues encoding smime from [pkijs](https://pkijs.org/) and decoding in openssl.

The [pkijs example](https://pkijs.org/examples/SMIMEEncryptionExample.html) encodes with a line ending problem in the mail header that needs to be corrected when copied out.

I've noticed a different in trailing "A"s in the output between the two implementations which makes me think it might be a difference in padding. However, I cannot see how to change the padding in either implementation of S/MIME. I experimented with the -stream switch for OpenSSL since that does change the padding, but adds too much.

First, here's the example key/cert:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Input text:

`Test message.`

The output from pkijs:

```
Content-Type: application/pkcs7-mime; name=smime.p7m;
 smime-type=enveloped-data
Content-Description: Enveloped Data
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=smime.p7m
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
From: sender@example.com
To: recipient@example.com
Subject: Example S/MIME encrypted message
Date: Tue, 15 May 2018 17:00:32 +0000
Message-Id: <1526403632814-3b7a2ea4-7320c042-592c9bb6@example.com>
MIME-Version: 1.0
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```

I fix the first line to make the message mail confirmant. The command I use to decode the output from pkijs is:

```
`openssl smime -decrypt -inkey privkey.pem -in smime2.txt
`
```

Which fails with:

> Error decrypting PKCS#7 structure 140101493268928:error:06065064:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt:crypto/evp/evp_enc.c:536:

I can use the same two keys to encrypt the message with OpenSSL using the command:

`openssl smime -encrypt -aes-128-cbc -to recipient@example.com -from sender@example.com -subject 'Example S/MIME encrypted message' -recip cert.pem -inkey privkey.pem cert.pem < text.txt`

And the output:

```
To: recipient@example.com
From: sender@example.com
Subject: Example S/MIME encrypted message
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="smime.p7m"
Content-Type: application/x-pkcs7-mime; smime-type=enveloped-data; name="smime.p7m"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
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==
```

Trying to decode this in pkijs has some problems that required the standard example code to be modified. I cloned the online example and changed the SMIMEEncryptionExample.js file content with sed replacing all instances of "innerHTML" with "value" so the script can access user posted data.

Attempting to decode this data in the pkijs form results in:

> ERROR DURING DECRYPTION PROCESS: Error: Object's schema was not verified against input data for RSAESOAEPParams

---

An update. Looking at the source code revealed pkijs uses CMS, and I was able to decode the browser encoded message using the following command:

`openssl cms -decrypt -aes-128-cbc -recip cmscertkey.pem -inkey cmskey.pem`

This command can be used to look at the structure of the encoded message:

`openssl cms -decrypt -aes-128-cbc -recip cmscertkey.pem -inkey cmskey.pem -noout -cmsout -print`

Here's some interesting output from the browser generated message:

```
         keyEncryptionAlgorithm: 
          algorithm: rsaesOaep (1.2.840.113549.1.1.7)
          parameter: SEQUENCE:
    0:d=0  hl=2 l=  47 cons: SEQUENCE          
    2:d=1  hl=2 l=  15 cons:  cont [ 0 ]        
    4:d=2  hl=2 l=  13 cons:   SEQUENCE          
    6:d=3  hl=2 l=   9 prim:    OBJECT            :sha512
   17:d=3  hl=2 l=   0 prim:    NULL              
   19:d=1  hl=2 l=  28 cons:  cont [ 1 ]        
   21:d=2  hl=2 l=  26 cons:   SEQUENCE          
   23:d=3  hl=2 l=   9 prim:    OBJECT            :mgf1
   34:d=3  hl=2 l=  13 cons:    SEQUENCE          
   36:d=4  hl=2 l=   9 prim:     OBJECT            :sha512
   47:d=4  hl=2 l=   0 prim:     NULL
```

The following command will encode a message with RSA-OAEP from openssl:

```
`openssl cms -encrypt -in text2.txt -from sender@example.com -to recipient@example.com -subject Testing -aes-128-cbc -recip cmscert.pem -keyopt rsa_padding_mode:oeap`
```

The message generated from this command:

```
    To: recipient@example.com
    From: sender@example.com
    Subject: Testing
    MIME-Version: 1.0
    Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="smime.p7m"
    Content-Type: application/pkcs7-mime; smime-type=enveloped-data; name="smime.p7m"
    Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

    MIIBpwYJKoZIhvcNAQcDoIIBmDCCAZQCAQAxggE/MIIBOwIBADAjMB4xHDAJBgNV
    BAYTAlJVMA8GA1UEAx4IAFQAZQBzAHQCAQEwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEHMAAEggEArEtI
    zD/OyE2y4cDuBenOuVQOK5brGsTLrSfpaSU1yJxPxA69oF5YmDi6Fo192IykhVQQ
    2gLaxq7rQv6+8z98RJ/R2vBm0kncKJ6908rd5O0y7Fg3GGnI4qDvrqxOmr47lHOb
    qZ8HJgrMTKn4S1LBVBENcnhtQFzAfMleLnc6hw6VDjowPYm8CTdtbjVCf1fNQ/wW
    E9QMLn3DVcDW861rK7oqf6ZT5srDVmHxNqlC17WcUR0Uhhfe8Zru8GMw4lM9/xhy
    PamXyBoCjhYLDhh9H+Ti7sQxXOEbgGz7HP5K5v7wofdStwAnbX42y7iasqpV0lvy
    RIRe32VGNw9wJBN82jBMBgkqhkiG9w0BBwEwHQYJYIZIAWUDBAECBBCSb7qkkRBQ
    d9bbdRTPY+ZigCDLIZ/IJjcCmjpmEXPT3UwXyWf5EP5S80CpRma4MvnMjQ==
```

This clears the RSAESOAEPParams error when decoding in the browser, but leads to a new error:

> ERROR DURING DECRYPTION PROCESS: DataError: The JWK "alg" member was inconsistent with that specified by the Web Crypto call

And and interesting difference in the cms structure output by OpenSSL with the most recent command:

```
        keyEncryptionAlgorithm: 
          algorithm: rsaesOaep (1.2.840.113549.1.1.7)
          parameter: SEQUENCE:
    0:d=0  hl=2 l=   0 cons: SEQUENCE
```

Mainly, the lack of key encryption algorithm parameters including mgf1.

I've looked over the source code and can't find a way to change these parameters in OpenSSL through commands.

Answer (score 0):

I [posted an issue](https://github.com/PeculiarVentures/PKI.js/issues/174) to the PKI.js site, and they patched their example code javascript code. I can now use bi-directional encryption between PKI.js and OpenSSL.